# Using Taylor polynomial to approximate the solution

Tags: real-analysis

> Use Taylor polynomials of degree $3$ to find approximate solutions of the equation
>
> $$\frac 13 x^3+x(e^x+e^{-x})-(e^x-e^{-x})-x=0.$$

I'm unsure what function we are supposed to find the Taylor polynomial of.

Comment: You can find the Taylor polynomial of the left-hand side. Then use the [formula for cubic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_solution_to_the_cubic_equation_with_real_coefficients) to find the roots.

Comment: Anyway, $x=0$ is an exact solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint:** for the exponential function: $$e^x=1+x+\frac {x^2}{2!}+\frac {x^3}{3!}+......$$

Answer (score 1):

As Theophile notes in the comments, you can find the Taylor polynomial of the left hand side,  and see what you get from there.

After taking the Taylor polynomial, which should be (hidden so you can try it yourself first)

> $x^3 - x= x(x^2-1)$

for which it should be easy to see the roots.